# Why are my imovies imported from iphoto sometimes sideways, upside down?

Tags: iphone

I finally figured out how to get my movies from my iphone to imovies - thank you - but now sometimes they are upside down or sideways in the big viewing screen top right.  How do I correct this?

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that it has something to do with the orientation you were holding the phone in when you took the movie.

iMovies is probably checking the orientation and trying to display the movie the "right way up". Look for an option that controls this.